# Load functions from file into REPL - Continuable Error

Tags: common-lisp, read-eval-print-loop, clisp

Up to now in my Lisp adventures I've just been pasting functions as written in a code editor into the REPL to run them, but I now have a program of sufficient size to build on that it will be convenient to use `(load "filename.lisp")` for the first time in my workflow.

Must I start using packages and/or namespacing to achieve this?

I find that when I use `load`, as above, I get

```
** - Continuable Error
DEFUN/DEFMACRO(CLASS): #<PACKAGE CLOS> is locked
If you continue (by typing 'continue'): Ignore the lock and proceed
The following restarts are also available:
SKIP           :R1      skip (DEFMACRO CLASS # ...)
RETRY          :R2      retry (DEFMACRO CLASS # ...)
STOP           :R3      stop loading file /Users/m/cl/ansi-cl/ch17-objects/177d-new-full.lisp
ABORT          :R4      Abort main loop
```

My `.lisp` file contains a macro called `class`, so I understand the error, sort of.

The thing is, when I paste the contents of the file directly into the REPL, I get no such error.

What's causing the difference in behaviour? 
Is it packages, namespaces or something else?

***I can indeed just type `continue`***, and the file will load, but I'd like to understand what is happening here; what's the cause of this "Continuable error", and how should I deal with it if at all?

Answer (score 4):

Package locking in [CLISP](http://clisp.org) is explained in [the manual](https://clisp.sourceforge.io/impnotes/pack-lock.html).

Symbol [`class`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_class.htm) is an ANSI CL symbol, so it cannot name any user-defined entity, and thus your program is not conforming, as explained in [11.1.2.1.2 Constraints on the COMMON-LISP Package for Conforming Programs](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/11_abab.htm).
You should rename your macro.

The lack of the error in the REPL is [a bug in homebrew clisp](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/43043). 
CLISP as distributed with ubuntu works correctly.
When I build CLISP from sources on Mac, it works correctly too.

Comment: In CLISP REPL upon starting it fresh I can type `(defun class () 42)`,  which is accepted without any warnings. Or just `(class)` -> `undefined function` or `(symbol-function #'class)` -> `undefined function`.  When you say bug, what do you mean there is a bug in?

Comment: I think that the correct behavior for `(defun class ...)` is to signal an error on both file loading/compilation, and in REPL. The lack of an error in REPL is, IMO, a bug.

Comment: How then do we explain that on a fresh REPL that `(symbol-function #'class)` gives `undefined function`?  Doesn't that mean it has no need to signal an error because there's nothing present to overwrite?

Comment: Please read 11.1.2.1.2 carefully. Yes, there is no function `class`, but the user is not allowed to define such a function anyway.

Comment: In GNU CLISP 2.49.93+ (2018-02-18) in the REPL I get an error, both for defining a function CLASS or a macro CLASS.

Comment: The point is not that you may be overwriting a function/macro/symbol-macro definition defined by the implementation. The point is that if two packages do what you do, namely define `class` as a function/macro/symbol-macro, the two definitions will collide.